# How does wrapper class object initialisation works?

Tags: java

In Java

```
Integer i=10;
```

`Integer` as wrapper class. How it is initialised while it's an object reference only? Could anybody explain that?

Comment: See [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
Integer i = 10;
```

is short for:

```
Integer i; // Variable declaration
i = 10; // Variable assignment
```

So first of all Java creates a variable called `i` which is allowed to refer to instances of type `Integer`.

After that the right side is executed, `10` is an integer literal of type `int` (see [JLS§3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)). Then Java tries to assign the `int` to your `Integer` variable `i`. The types differ, for a regular case the assignment would not be possible.

However, Java is able to automatically convert `int` to `Integer` and vice versa. This is called **autoboxing**, Java can do this for all primitives and their wrapper (see [JLS§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)).

So Java converts your `int` `10` to the wrapper type `Integer` by using `Integer.valueOf(10)`. In fact, since the number is small (`-128` to `+127`) the method returns a cached `Integer` out of an internal pool instead of creating a new instance.

So after *Java magic* your code is:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(10);
```

which is a valid assignment as the right side is also an `Integer` and not an `int` anymore.

---

Actually the usage of `Integer.valueOf` is not described in the JLS. It only says that Java must be able to automatically convert `int` to `Integer` (from [JLS§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)):

> If `p` is a value of type `int`, then boxing conversion converts `p` into a reference `r` of class and type `Integer`, such that `r.intValue() == p`.

But most JVM implementations use that method (you can see that in the resulting byte code).